# Checking if the number is a decimal.Decimal type in python

Tags: python, types, decimal

Variable 'a' could be of type - int/float/decimal.Decimal (but not a string)

I want to check if its a decimal.Decimal type.

Following works:

```
import decimal
a = decimal.Decimal(4)

if type(a) is decimal.Decimal:
    print('yes decimal')
else: 
    print('not decimal')
```

But, is there a righter way of doing the same?
tnx.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) which outputs `True` or `False`.

```
result = isinstance(a, decimal.Decimal)
print(result)
```